# Is it possible to combine two iPhones with tethering to increase bandwidth or fault tolerance?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, tethering

I'm using a MacBook as a "server" and want to keep it always connected to the internet, over cellular.

I have two mobile phones (one GSM, one CDMA) and would like to connect to each of them to achieve fault tolerance, or ideally, increased bandwidth.

Is there any way for me to

1. Simultaneously connect to two iPhones
2. Use the joined connection for fault tolerance, or increased bandwidth

I have the option to use Wifi, USB-C, or bluetooth to combine these phones, in any combination

Comment: How are you connecting to the iPhones(s)? Is it via Wi-Fi hotspot?

Comment: @NimeshNeema updated

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, you can connect two iPhones simultaneously; it's called [multi-homing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming) (this is good for fault tolerance).  The [`pf` firewall](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) has this capability and is built into macOS, but writing the rules file is outside the scope of this question.

However, you can't combine the bandwidth to get a larger "pipe."  You'll still have two smaller pipes.   In order to combine bandwidth, you will need to aggregate the pipes or [**bond**](https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/network-bonding-types-network-bonding/) them which is something that the ISP/carrier will need to do for you - different carriers (GSM and CDMA) are very unlikely to do this.

Comment: but if I move to the same carrier you think a bond is possible?

Comment: Technically? Yes.  Practically? No.  More than likely they will try to find a wireless solution that will meet your needs.  You'll have to explain the issue you're having and see what solutions they come up with.  And... you can't ask the "consumer" rep on the phone at your wireless company - you need to talk to an "Enterprise" rep.

Comment: @TLDR moving to the same carrier would possbly be an arrow to the knee as you probably want to either increase fault tolerance *and* safety againt interruptions?